# php count and add each values from MySQL table row

Tags: mysql, count, addition, rows

I don't know if it's possible to count and add from each mysql table row.

this is what i have:

```
id: visits:
1 : 23    :
2 : 53    :
3 : 12    :
4 : 33    :
```

I want to count and add all visits from each rows, the total visits i should get is 121 visits.

if this make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(visits)as visitCounts FROM (
   SELECT visits FROM tableName
) v
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8a0f4/5

Comment: Thanks but it works this way: SELECT SUM(visits) as visitCounts FROM tableName